# Unable to establish SSL connection

Tags: internet, ssl

Yesterday,I installed Ubuntu along with Windows 10(dual booting).Now,in Ubuntu,for any entered web address the firefox says "Secure connection failed".Sometimes few sites like mozilla addon sites opens(slowly),but all other sites fail to load.Also when using wget ,"Unable to establish SSL connection appears.
Please help.I am new to Ubuntu.
I am connected via wifi(mobile hotspot).
Also when i connect via usb tethering,all sites load fine and there is no problem.

Comment: check your system clock.

Comment: Clock is correct.

Comment: can you post the output of `curl -v --head https://www.google.com/` ?

Comment: @bistoco It says curl not found.and when installing by "sudo apt install curl" ,the progress bar halts at 0%

Comment: Can you do `ping 8.8.8.8`?